# Sql queries for getting information from GTFS files in Java

Tags: mysql, sql, gtfs

I'm working on a project for school which uses [gtfs database](http://code.google.com/p/gtfsdb/) (MySQL).
I wrote some code that parses the gtfs files and inserts them into MySQL DB (each file is a table in my DB).
I'm trying to write two SQL queries:

1. Given a `stationId`, `time`, and `line number` - I want to get all trips that pass by this station in the next 10 minutes.
2. Given a `tripId`, `directionId` and `stopId` - I want to get all the remaining stations in this trip (in order to draw on a map the stations to come in my trip).

Does anyone knows how can I state this SQL queries in Java?

---

I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM stops, routes, stop_times, calendar, trips
where departure_time > "08:24:00"
  and departure_time < "16:40:00"
  and route_short_name = "10"
  and stops.stop_id = 29335
  and stops.stop_id = stop_times.stop_id
  and stop_times.trip_id = trips.trip_id
  and calendar.service_id = trips.service_id
  and calendar.sunday = 1
```

Comment: BTW - I'm using the static gtfs files

Comment: `SELECT  * FROM stops,  routes, stop_times, calendar, trips
where  departure_time > "08:24:00" 
        and departure_time < "16:40:00" 
        and route_short_name = "10"
        and stops.stop_id = 29335
        and stops.stop_id = stop_times.stop_id
        and stop_times.trip_id = trips.trip_id
        and calendar.service_id = trips.service_id
        and calendar.sunday = 1`

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this problem exactly for GTFS data in Belgium. The code is available on github:

https://github.com/iRail/MIVBSTIBResource/blob/master/MIVBSTIBStopTimesDao.php